# lua userdata c++ destructor

Tags: lua, destructor, garbage-collection

In lua, for memory allocated with lua_newuserdata,
is it possible to register a destructor,
so that the destructor is called when the memory region is garbage collected by lua?

Thanks!

Comment: Do be aware that since Lua is garbage collected, any particular `userdata` may not be collected as soon as you'd like or in any particular order.

Comment: Yeah; in this particular case, it's not crucial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it is. If the userdata has a metatable with a function called __gc, it will be called when the userdata is garbage collected, with the userdata as it's parameter. Have a look at http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.10.1